# Limited range HTML colour picker

Tags: html, colors

I need to create a colour picker for a site which wouldn't be a problem, but I want to essentially have a slider that picks colours from this range:

[image]

How would I go about this?

Comment: Well, there's no native way of doing it, so I'd imagine a long and short div, with a gradient background, with a JavaScript click handler to calculate the position of where it was clicked, thus determining the color at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can transfer this image into CANVAS, you can pick the color from here.

See:

[Looking for a jQuery plugin to pick a color from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345739/looking-for-a-jquery-plugin-to-pick-a-color-from-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine something similar to this. It could probably use some (a lot) of tweaking, but that's the gist of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #color_picker {
            background: #e8f230; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, hsla(63,88%,57%,1) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,hsla(63,88%,57%,1)), color-stop(100%,hsla(0,0%,0%,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(63,88%,57%,1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,0%,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(left, hsla(63,88%,57%,1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,0%,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, hsla(63,88%,57%,1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,0%,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to right, hsla(63,88%,57%,1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,0%,1) 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e8f230', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="color_picker"></div>

<div id="target">Test</div>

<script>
    var picker = color_picker;
    var result = target;
    picker.onclick = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        result.style.backgroundColor = "hsl(63, 88%, " + (50 - ((e.offsetX/picker.clientWidth) * 50)) + "%)";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want straight HTML, you could use the `MAP` tag and pass the relevant value using HTML-GET...  Otherwise, a bit of JavaScript perhaps?

Have you actually looked around for existing code?

Here's something: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp

---

From comments:

> w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as
>   reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the PHP Manual,
>   for JavaScript, there's Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN). See
>   w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Fair enough.  It was simply an example.  It's faster to find source code on google than to press the "Ask Question" button on stackoverflow.  Here's another: http://jscolor.com/ with directly linked LGPL source code.  Modify to suit your purposes.

Comment: I'd happily take a JS solution and yes i've had a look, but I can only find ones that let you pick from the full RGB range or lighter/darker ranges of a single colour.

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.